# Change Ellipse Fill Value with data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have some problem in changing `Ellipse` `Fill` value based on data binding a boolean.

- `true` = `Lime` colour
- `false` = `Red` colour

My code does not prompt out any error but also does not show fill value colours.

WPF XAML code:

```
<Ellipse x:Name="damageSpoolSlot1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="45" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" Grid.Column="1" Margin="203.4,377.2,0,0" Grid.Row="2">
   <Ellipse.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DamageSpoolSlot1PresenceSensorOn}" Value="false">
               <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DamageSpoolSlot1PresenceSensorOn}" Value="true">
               <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Lime"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </Ellipse.Style>
</Ellipse>
```

Code-Behind:

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding("DamageSpoolSlot1PresenceSensorOn")
{
    Source = MyBinding.Instance
};
BindingOperations.SetBinding(damageSpoolSlot1, Ellipse.FillProperty, myBinding);
```

My data binding code:

```
public class MyBinding : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private static volatile MyBinding instance;
   private static object syncRoot = new Object();
   public static MyBinding Instance
   {
      get
      {
         if (instance == null)
         {
            lock (syncRoot)
            {
               if (instance == null)
                  instance = new MyBinding();
            }
         }
         return instance;
       }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool _DamageSpoolSlot1PresenceSensorOn = false;

    public bool DamageSpoolSlot1PresenceSensorOn
    {
       get { return _DamageSpoolSlot1PresenceSensorOn; }
       set
       {
          if (value != _DamageSpoolSlot1PresenceSensorOn)
          {
             _DamageSpoolSlot1PresenceSensorOn = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("DamageSpoolSlot1PresenceSensorOn");
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `MyBinding.Instance`? Where is the _data binding code_, in code-behind, somewhere else?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear code, I have one class called MyBinding that put all my data binding code inside it. I try edit it more clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data triggers in your style bind to the `DataContext` of the `Ellipse`. This means they expect an object that has a property `DamageSpoolSlot1PresenceSensorOn`. However, your binding fails in two ways.

1. The binding already binds to the `DamageSpoolSlot1PresenceSensorOn` of the `MyBinding.Instance`, so the data triggers will try to bind to another sub property `DamageSpoolSlot1PresenceSensorOn` that simply does not exist, the `DataContext` already is this property.
2. The binding binds the `Fill` property, which expects a `Brush`, but the data triggers bind to the `DataContext` of the `Ellipse`, not the `Fill` property.

Change the binding like this, so it will deliver the `Instace` to the `DataContext` property.

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding()
{
   Source = MyBinding.Instance
};
BindingOperations.SetBinding(damageSpoolSlot1, Ellipse.DataContextProperty, myBinding);
```

---

Another simpler option is to create the binding to the `MyBinding.Instance` directly in XAML. Bind the `DataContext` property using a binding that specifies the static `MyBinding.Instance` as `Source` with the `x:Static` markup extension.

```
<Ellipse x:Name="damageSpoolSlot1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="45" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" Margin="203.4,377.2,0,0"
         DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MyBinding.Instance}}">
   <Ellipse.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
         <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DamageSpoolSlot1PresenceSensorOn}" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Lime"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </Ellipse.Style>
</Ellipse>
```

---

As @Clemens pointed out, you could also simply set the `DataContext` in code-behind.

```
damageSpoolSlot1.DataContext = MyBinding.Instance;
```

Comment: Or just set the DataContext in code: `damageSpoolSlot1.DataContext = MyBinding.Instance;`

Comment: Yes, I had changed to this way: `damageSpoolSlot1.DataContext = MyBinding.Instance;` 
But I just figured out that the main error is this part: 
`<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DamageSpoolSlot1PresenceSensorOn}" Value="false">` 
The value cannot read true or false, so I change to int 0 and 1, it's work now. Thank you.

Comment: @newbie Your observation is not quite correct. The Value of a DataTrigger on a bool property should either be `True` or `False`.

Comment: @Clemens When I use `private bool _DamageSpoolSlot1PresenceSensorOn = false;` and `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DamageSpoolSlot1PresenceSensorOn}" Value="false">` The value seems do not read true and false. So I change to `private int _DamageSpoolSlot1PresenceSensorOn = 0;` `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DamageSpoolSlot1PresenceSensorOn}" Value="0">`, Then it's work and it's change the ellipse colour.

Comment: @newbie @Clemens is right. Just as proof, I tested `true`/`false` and `True`/`False` both on .NET Framework 4.7.2 and .NET Core 3.1. Both work as expected, although I completely agree with @Clemens to either use `True` or `False`.

Comment: @newbie Also note that you would typically not have two DataTriggers on a bool property. There would instead be a Style Setter for the default Background, and a single DataTrigger that changes it when the bool property does not have its default value.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you, I simplified the style and added your suggestion.